# Update div in different controller with g:formRemote Grails

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap-3, grails-2.3

I have a template that I want to reuse in another view. The template contains a table view. The table view is totally editable. When I edit the table view, it makes calls back to a controller and re renders the tableview, using a g:formRemote tag. I want to use the same template with the same g:formRemote tag in a different controller/view. My issue is that the new template won't re-render. Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: can you post some of the code for the gsp pages?

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I can use the same template in different views once the update tag in the g:formRemote are the same in both gsp's